# if set spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=time, will retry work? or retry work in specified ack-mode?

Tags: spring-kafka

[Spring Kafka - How to Retry with @KafkaListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831034/spring-kafka-how-to-retry-with-kafkalistener)

`spring-kafka SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` if set `spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=time`, will retry work? or retry work in specified ack-mode, such as MANUAL MANUAL_IMMEDIATE.

```
@Value("${${sync.kafka.header.source.id}}")
private String headerSourceId;

@Value("${sync.kafka.from.id}")
private String syncKafkaFromId;

@Value("${sync.kafka.to.id}")
private String syncKafkaToId;

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

@Autowired
private ConsumerFactory consumerFactory;

@KafkaListener(topics = "${sync.kafka.topics}")
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record,
                   @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                   @Header(value = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = false) String messageKey,
                   @Header(value = "${sync.kafka.header.source.id}", required = false) String customHeader,
                   @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    log.info("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
    log.info("topic: {}", topic);
    log.info("message key: {}", messageKey);
    log.info("custom header: {}", customHeader);
    log.info("messageHeaders: {}", messageHeaders);

    ProducerRecord<Object, Object> ProducerRecord = new ProducerRecord(topic,record.key(), record.value());
    ProducerRecord.headers().add(new RecordHeader(headerSourceId, syncKafkaFromId.getBytes()));

    kafkaTemplate.send(ProducerRecord);
}
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
    // or factory.setRetryTemplate(aRetryTemplate);
    // and factory.setRecoveryCallback(aRecoveryCallback);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, offset will come under while consuming but not producing for this `I want if kafkaTemplate.send error, offset don't commit.

`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831034/spring-kafka-how-to-retry-with-kafkalistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use manual, record or batch ack modes when using the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`. You should also set the `ackOnError` container property to `false` and set `enable.auto.commit` to `false`.