# How to retry with spring kafka version 2..2

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry

Just trying to find out a simple example with spring-kafka 2.2 that works with a KafkaListener, to retry last failed message. If a message fails, the message should be redirected to another Topic where the retries attempts will be made.
We will have 4 topics. 
**topic**, **retryTopic**, **sucessTopic** and **errorTopic**
If topic fails, should be redirected to retryTopic where the 3 attempts to retry will be made. If those attempts fails, must redirect to **errorTopic**. In case of sucess on both **topic** and **retryTopic**, should be redirected to the **sucessTopic**.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little simpler with Spring Boot 2.2.4 and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.3.5:

(2.2.x shown below).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So60172304Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60172304Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("topic").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic retryTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("retryTopic").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic successTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("successTopic").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic errorTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("errorTopic").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("topic", "failAlways");
            template.send("topic", "onlyFailFirst");
            template.send("topic", "good");
        };
    }

    /*
     * A custom container factory is needed until 2.3.6 is released because the
     * container customizer was not applied before then.
     */
    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void initializeContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> instance,
                            KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint) {

                        super.initializeContainer(instance, endpoint);
                        customizer(template).configure(instance);
                    }

        };
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
//      factory.setContainerCustomizer(customizer(template)); // after 2.3.6
        return factory;
    }

    private ContainerCustomizer<Object, Object, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object>>
            customizer(KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        return container -> {
            if (container.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0].equals("topic")) {
                container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                        new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                                (cr, ex) -> new TopicPartition("retryTopic", cr.partition())),
                        new FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)));
            }
            else if (container.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0].equals("retryTopic")) {
                container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                        new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                                (cr, ex) -> new TopicPartition("errorTopic", cr.partition())),
                        new FixedBackOff(5000L, 2L)));
            }
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    public Listener(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.1", topics = "topic")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        System.out.println("topic: " + in);
        if (in.toLowerCase().contains("fail")) {
            throw new RuntimeException(in);
        }
        this.template.send("successTopic", in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.2", topics = "retryTopic")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println("retryTopic: " + in);
        if (in.startsWith("fail")) {
            throw new RuntimeException(in);
        }
        this.template.send("successTopic", in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.3", topics = "successTopic")
    public void listen3(String in) {
        System.out.println("successTopic: " + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.4", topics = "errorTopic")
    public void listen4(String in) {
        System.out.println("errorTopic: " + in);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

result:

```
topic: failAlways
retryTopic: failAlways
topic: onlyFailFirst
topic: good
successTopic: good
retryTopic: failAlways
retryTopic: failAlways
retryTopic: onlyFailFirst
errorTopic: failAlways
successTopic: onlyFailFirst
```

With Spring Boot 2.1.12 and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.2.12:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So601723041Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So601723041Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("topic", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic retryTopic() {
        return new NewTopic("retryTopic", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic successTopic() {
        return new NewTopic("successTopic", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic errorTopic() {
        return new NewTopic("errorTopic", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("topic", "failAlways");
            template.send("topic", "onlyFailFirst");
            template.send("topic", "good");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void initializeContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> instance,
                            KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint) {

                        super.initializeContainer(instance, endpoint);
                        customize(instance, template);
                    }

        };
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void initializeContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> instance,
                            KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint) {

                        super.initializeContainer(instance, endpoint);
                        customize(instance, template);
                    }

        };
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(3));
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(5000L);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return factory;
    }

    private void customize(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> container,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        if (container.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0].equals("topic")) {
            container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                    new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                            (cr, ex) -> new TopicPartition("retryTopic", cr.partition())),
                    0));
        }
        else if (container.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0].equals("retryTopic")) {
            container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                    new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                            (cr, ex) -> new TopicPartition("errorTopic", cr.partition())),
                    0)); // no retries here - retry template instead.
        }
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    public Listener(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.1", topics = "topic")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        System.out.println("topic: " + in);
        if (in.toLowerCase().contains("fail")) {
            throw new RuntimeException(in);
        }
        this.template.send("successTopic", in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.2", topics = "retryTopic", containerFactory = "retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println("retryTopic: " + in);
        if (in.startsWith("fail")) {
            throw new RuntimeException(in);
        }
        this.template.send("successTopic", in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.3", topics = "successTopic")
    public void listen3(String in) {
        System.out.println("successTopic: " + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.4", topics = "errorTopic")
    public void listen4(String in) {
        System.out.println("errorTopic: " + in);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

To change the payload in the published record, you could use something like this (call `MyRepublisher.setNewValue("new value");`).

```java
public class MyRepublisher extends DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> newValue = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public MyRepublisher(KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template,
            BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition> destinationResolver) {

        super(template, destinationResolver);
    }

    @Override
    protected ProducerRecord<Object, Object> createProducerRecord(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record,
            TopicPartition topicPartition, RecordHeaders headers) {

        ProducerRecord<Object, Object> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicPartition.topic(),
                        topicPartition.partition() < 0 ? null : topicPartition.partition(),
                        record.key(), newValue.get(), headers);
        newValue.remove();
        return producerRecord;
    }

    public static void setNewValue(String value) {
        newValue.set(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to send an specfic object to the errorTopic. Is that possible?

Comment: The first parameter to the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` can be any implementation of `ConsumerRecordRecoverer`. You can do whatever you want in the "recoverer". The `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` simply sends the failed inbound data.

Comment: But I need to access the "topic" object before creating the "errorTopic". How can I access the "topic" object before sending the message to the "errorTopic"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "topic object". The topic name is available in `record.topic()`.

Comment: I saw that I can access the object that the listener called "Topic" receives in your example by the method value() in the ConsumerRecord. How can I change it? We are using spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE. I want to send a different message to the errorTopic.

Comment: I still can't understand what you mean - the recoverer (DLPR) creates a `ProducerRecord` from the `ConsumerRecord` - you can do whatever you want in a custom recoverer. Perhaps you can edit the question to show what you don't understand?

Comment: You can't change the `ConsumerRecord` in the listener before throwing the exception, if that's what you mean (unless the value() is mutable, in which case you can make changes to **it**). If you want to communicate some information to the recoverer, you could use a `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Lets say that the "Topic" Listener     @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.1", topics = "topic") public void listen1(String in) consumes the message "Gary" and after it fails 3 times, I want to redirect the message to the error topic with the string "Gary Error".

Comment: It worked for me. But now, I have another situation where I have to call the retry topic without any exception thrown. And if the retry topic does not succeed(without exception), calls the error topic. Is this possible? The topic communicates with a SOAP, where when this SOAP service fails to communicate with a government system, this SOAP will return an object to me(not an exception). And based on this response object, I need to call the retry Topic, and if the SOAP reponse returns certains objects in the retryTopic, I need to send it to the error Topic.

Comment: Don't ask additional questions in comments. This answer already has a lot of comments and the admins don't like that. That said, I can't understand what you are saying - I don't know what "call the retry topic" means. Ask a new question with more details.