# JUnit tests With Spring Boot 2.1.12 and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.2.12

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry, spring-kafka-test

Just trying to find out a simple example with Spring Boot 2.1.12 and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.2.12 that works with a KafkaListener, to retry last failed message. If a message fails, the message should be redirected to another Topic where the retries attempts will be made. We will have 4 topics. topic, retryTopic, sucessTopic and errorTopic If topic fails, should be redirected to retryTopic where the 3 attempts to retry will be made. If those attempts fails, must redirect to errorTopic. In case of sucess on both topic and retryTopic, should be redirected to the sucessTopic. And I need to cover 90% of the cases with **JUnit** Test.

Comment: I already answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172304/how-to-retry-with-spring-kafka-version-2-2/60173862#60173862). Why open a new question with essentially the same information. What more do you need? Why don't you comment on that answer?

Comment: I'm new in the forum(sorry), it's because I a need sample with JUnit tests. Don't know all the rules yet.

Comment: Okay, Mr. Russell. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, spring-kafka and spring-kafka-test are on 2.2.8.RELEASE version.

Answer (score 0):

> 2.2.8.RELEASE

That is 6 months old.

You should always use the latest version in a minor release to make sure you have all bug fixes; the current 2.2.x version is 2.2.12.

I have reworked my 2.2.x answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172304/how-to-retry-with-spring-kafka-version-2-2/60173862#60173862) with an example of how you might test such an application. It uses an embedded test Kafka broker.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So601723041Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So601723041Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void initializeContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> instance,
                            KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint) {

                        super.initializeContainer(instance, endpoint);
                        customize(instance, template);
                    }

        };
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void initializeContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> instance,
                            KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint) {

                        super.initializeContainer(instance, endpoint);
                        customize(instance, template);
                    }

        };
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(3));
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(5000L);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return factory;
    }

    private void customize(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> container,
            KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {

        if (container.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0].equals("topic")) {
            container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                    new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                            (cr, ex) -> new TopicPartition("retryTopic", cr.partition())),
                    0));
        }
        else if (container.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0].equals("retryTopic")) {
            container.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(
                    new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template,
                            (cr, ex) -> new TopicPartition("errorTopic", cr.partition())),
                    0)); // no retries here - retry template instead.
        }
    }

}

@Component
public class Listener {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    private SomeService service;

    public Listener(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, SomeService service) {
        this.template = template;
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void setService(SomeService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.1", topics = "topic")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        this.service.process(in);
        this.template.send("successTopic", in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.2", topics = "retryTopic", containerFactory = "retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        this.service.retry(in);
        this.template.send("successTopic", in);
    }

}

public interface SomeService {

    void process(String in);

    void retry(String in);

}

@Component
public class DefaultService implements SomeService {

    @Override
    public void process(String in) {
        System.out.println("topic: " + in);
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(String in) {
        System.out.println("retryTopic: " + in);
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

Test case:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers = ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}")
public class So601723041ApplicationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embedded = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, 1,
            "topic", "retryTopic", "successTopic", "errorTopic");

    @Autowired
    private Listener listener;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        TestService testService = spy(new TestService());
        this.listener.setService(testService);
        template.send("topic", "failAlways");
        template.send("topic", "onlyFailFirst");
        template.send("topic", "good");
        Map<String, Object> props = KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("test1", "false", embedded.getEmbeddedKafka());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        Consumer<Integer, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        embedded.getEmbeddedKafka().consumeFromEmbeddedTopics(consumer, "successTopic");
        List<ConsumerRecord<Integer, String>> received = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = 0;
        while (received.size() < 2 && n++ < 10) {
            ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            records.forEach(rec -> received.add(rec));
        }
        assertThat(received.size() == 2);
        consumer.close();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test2");
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        embedded.getEmbeddedKafka().consumeFromEmbeddedTopics(consumer, "errorTopic");
        n = 0;
        while (received.size() < 3 && n++ < 10) {
            ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            records.forEach(rec -> received.add(rec));
        }
        assertThat(received.size() == 3);
        consumer.close();
        verify(testService, times(3)).process(anyString());
        verify(testService, times(4)).retry(anyString());
        assertThat(received).extracting(rec -> rec.value())
                .contains("good", "onlyFailFirst", "failAlways");
    }

    public static class TestService implements SomeService {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        @Override
        public void process(String in) {
            System.out.println("topic: " + in);
            if (in.toLowerCase().contains("fail")) {
                throw new RuntimeException(in);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(String in) {
            System.out.println("retryTopic: " + in);
            if (in.startsWith("fail")) {
                throw new RuntimeException(in);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

EMMA shows 97.2% coverage

POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so60172304-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so60172304-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I just re-ran it against 2.2.8 and the test still runs green.

Comment: Unfortunately embeddedTopics are not being consumed. Do you know what it could be? records are with size 0.

Comment: Do you have `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest` in `application.properties`? New consumers consume from the end of a topic by default and there is a race in the test between sending the records and the consumers starting. The above code is from a completely working application.

Comment: Yes, I did. I had to put this configuration(spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true) in the application.properties, because without it, the application doesn't start.

Comment: Why? What bean(s) are you overriding in your test? My test had no overrides.

Comment: I have to communicate with an SAP using SOAP. Then I got this exception. The bean 'countryClient', defined in class path resource [br/com/company/config/ReceiverConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in file [C:\Users\kafka_projects\csm-microservice\target\classes\br\com\company\service\CountryClient.class] and overriding is disabled.

Comment: That's irrelevant to this test case so allowing bean override is fine; it should have no bearing on whether your consumer in the test gets any records; I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to figure out what's going on. As I said, the test above works fine so something is wrong with your code/config. I can't really help more.

Comment: I added the pom.

Comment: Do you know what this error could be:?  org.apache.kafka.test.TestUtils          : Error deleting C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-2102474369578365822

Comment: There have been some occasional issues with shutting down the embedded broker on Windows but we haven't got to the bottom of it; some kind of timing issue within the Kafka code itself. **But make sure you close any consumers or producers you create manually in your tests** (Spring will take care of closing any that it manages).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage>
    // specified in
    // pom.xml
    marshaller.setContextPath("br.com.company.ws");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public CountryClient countryClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    CountryClient client = new CountryClient();
    client.setDefaultUri(link);
    WebServiceTemplate template = client.getWebServiceTemplate();
    template.setMessageSender(new WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth(username, password));
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}
```

@Service
public class CountryClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

```
@Value("${spring.link.consumer.link}")
private String link;


public ZfifNfMaoResponse getCountry(ZfifNfMao zfifNfMao) {

    zfifNfMao = new ZfifNfMao();

    ZfifNfMaoResponse response = (ZfifNfMaoResponse)getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(link, zfifNfMao);

    return response;
}
```

}