# Call the retry listener from inside another listener maintaining with the whole retry Logic

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry

We are using spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE. I have an specific situation where I need help. I have 4 topics **topic, retryTopic, successTopic and errorTopic.** If **topic** fails, should be redirected to **retryTopic** where the 3 attempts to retry will be made. If those attempts fails, must redirect to **errorTopic**. In case of sucess on both **topic** and **retryTopic**, should be redirected to the sucessTopic. This situation is already implemented based on the question [How to retry with spring kafka version 2..2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172304/how-to-retry-with-spring-kafka-version-2-2/60173862).
But now, I have a new situation where I need to call the **retryTopic** listener from inside the **topic** listener based on a business logic error without an Exception been thrown(it already calls the **retryTopic** when an exception is thrown and it must remain with this behavior). And I also need to know on which retry attempt number the **retryTopic** is been called as a paramater of the listener bellow.

```
 @KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.2", topics = "retryTopic")
 public void listen2(String in) {
            RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Void, RuntimeException>() {
        @Override
        public Void doWithRetry(RetryContext retryContext) throws RuntimeException {
             // Can I get the retry count here? It didn't work
             Integer count =RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount());
            return this.doWithRetry(retryContext);
        }
    }); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you can't call one listener from another (but you won't get retries unless you call it using a `RetryTemplate` in the first method).

If you use a `RetryTemplate` configured on the container factory to do the retries (rather than adding a `BackOff` to the `SeektoCurrentErrorHandler` in versions 2.3.x and higher), you can obtain the retry count (starting at zero) like this...

```
@KafkaListener(id = "so60172304.2", topics = "retryTopic")
public void listen2(String in) {
    int retryCount = RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount();
    ...
}
```

`getContext()` will return null if you call this directly from the first method (unless you wrap the call in a `RetryTemplate.execute()`).

In 2.5.x a delivery attempt header will be available (optionally) even if using the `SeektoCurrentErrorHandler` with a `BackOff` instead of using a `RetryTemplate` in the container factory.

Comment: I urge you to keep up-to-date with the latest version in your minor release, even if you can't move up to a newer minor release (the current latest is 2.4.4). The latest 2.1.x is 2.1.14 - 6 bug fix releases since your version which is 8 months old.

Comment: I've edited my question with some code, can I get the retry count like that in spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE?

Comment: You don't need another retry template there; that would be nested inside the main template. You only need a retry template if you call this listener method from another (and you need it there). PLEASE STOP USING OLD RELEASES.

Comment: It's not my decision to use old releases. I've already told companie's architects to change the archetype and they didn't want to. You don't need to yell at me.

Comment: I'm sorry; it's just very frustrating; it's hard enough to support 4 minor releases 2.4, 2.3, 2.2 and 1.3 without having to answer questions about ancient point releases for each. I spend a lot of my time adding features and fixing bugs; I sometimes wonder if I am wasting my time. Your architects need to get with the plan. Boot 2.1 (and hence SK 2.2) goes [end of life in November](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/10/spring-boot-2-1-x-eol-november-1st-2020).